# Calculate a duration of time when the wind speed was continiously higher than previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

here is my dataframe,

[image]

I want to add a new column, which shows how long (seconds) the wind speed (Скорость ветра, м/с) was continuously greater than previous value. What i tried is working wrong,

```py
df['seconds_until'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(df.loc[(df['Скорость ветра, м/с'] < x['Скорость ветра, м/с']) & (df['DateTime'] > x['DateTime']), 'DateTime'].min()) - pd.to_datetime(x[
'DateTime']), axis=1)
df
```

Comment: How is it wrong? What did you expect? What do you get instead? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
Code:

```
group = df['Скорость ветра, м/с'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()

g = df.groupby(group)['Date'].transform

df['duration'] = g('max')-g('min')
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it but it also giving me not i want. For rows 1-4 where  "Скорость ветра, м/с' is lower than  3.7 (row 0), expacted duration  at row 5 should be 40 seconds. How can i manage this?

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible input

Answer (score 1):

I used a mask to identify increasing wind speeds.  Next, I accumulate the wind speeds and reset on 0

```
df=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/main/docs/data/seattle-weather.csv",parse_dates=["date"])

df.set_index("date",inplace=True)
df=df.sort_index()
df.columns

df["mark"]=df.wind.shift(1)<df.wind
df["wind_incr"]=df.wind.mask(~df.mark,0)

prev_accum=0
accum=0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.wind_incr>prev_accum:
        accum+=row.wind_incr
    else:
        accum=0
    df.loc[index,"accumulative"]=accum
    prev_accum=accum

df["accumulative"].plot()
plt.show()
```